# Error keeps coming providing the MYSQLI_ASSOC parameter is removed

Tags: php, mysql

my sessions.php

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
```

though i get the login page am getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbUgR.png), provided the right parameter is being passed1

my welcome.php

```
<?php
   include('sessions.php');
?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Welcome </title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
      <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_SESSION` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your previous query isn't been executed properly.

From what I see, it looks like it's unable to locate your sessions.php file, and therefore it's unable to recognize $_SESSION['login_user'].

You could use a bit of debugging and use functions like [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

```
var_dump($_SESSION['login_user']); // Check your result. It's probably coming as NULL.

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM admin WHERE username = '".$user_check."' ") or die(mysqli_error($db));  

if ($ses_sql) {
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the main problem is in your `session.php` page. Your `$_SESSION['login_user']` is not have any value thats why your `query` is not `executing` and anything rest is not working.

Always we must ensure that `variables` which we are taking in use have some value then we should use them also use `mysqli_error()` `functions` to check any `error` if any.

so change your code with this

```
session.php

  <?php
  include('config.php');
  session_start(); 
 //echo  $_SESSION['login_user'];die 
  if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
       $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

       $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from admin where username = '$user_check' ") or die(mysqli_error($db));

       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

       $login_session = $row['username'];
    }
       else
         {
          header("location:login.php");
       }
```

*Use **PDO** for securing your code from `sql injection`